# Why is my color class not being applied to my <p> text?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to simplify my stylesheet so if I want to change the color of my default paragraph text or any text I can just add for example (class="blue") So I have a list of general colors to use on any text like this:

```
.dark-grey { color: #232323; }
.med-grey { color: #616161; }
.light-grey { color: #e2e3e4; }
.orange { color: #f66511; }
.light-orange { color: #f66511; }
.blue { color: #2251a4; }
.white { color: #ffffff; }
```

In my example, why is my **Subaru Forester**

not turning blue?

Do I have to put all those colors under my div for the colors to work?

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/1ysq0c3y/7/

Here's my code:

```
<p class="orange"><strong>Honda CRV</p>
<p>See full features and specs of the 2014 Honda CR-V SUV at the Official Honda Web site. View seating dimensions, EPA mileage ratings and engineering</p>


<div id="wrapper-landing">
<p class="blue"><strong>Subaru Forester</strong></p>
<p>Fuji Heavy Industries, the company that builds Subaru vehicles, is a master of the economics of scale and, until the arrival this year of the 2013 BRZ sports car, built an entire product line from just two different vehicle platforms, two different power trains and, of course, two different versions of the company's Symmetrical All-Wheel Drive (AWD) system. The new 2014 Subaru Forester, a popular compact crossover SUV, springs from the company's small car platform, which also provides the basis for the Impreza, the WRX and the XV Crosstrek models.</p>

</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
    color: #666666;
    font-family: 'SegoeRegular',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.blue { color: #2251a4; }
.orange { color: #f66511; }

#wrapper-landing {
    width: 916px;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper-landing p {
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    font-family: 'SegoeRegular',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

Comment: `#wrapper-landing p` is overriding `.blue`.

Comment: `#wrapper-landing p` is given a higher priority because you are narrowing the selection and it has an ID attached. You would need to add !important to the color classes to override, or you can be more specific with your css selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the color with the parent class.

```
#wrapper-landing p { color ...}
```

If you want the blue class to override its parent, add !important to your css.

```
.blue { color: #2251a4 !important; }
```

Comment: normally people try to suggest relying on !important only as last resorts, but in this case I think !important is acceptable as it is just a color override

Answer (score 2):

You're falling prey to CSS Specificity rules. You have another css rule that is more specific than just your `.blue` class that is overriding it. In this case it is your `#wrapper-landing p` rule. You will have to make it more specific for example:

```
#wrapper-landing p.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example of "Subaru Forester" doesn't become blue as another CSS selector, `#wrapper-landing p`, is more specific than `.blue` (in this case 101 vs 10). The CSS selector with the highest specificity wins.

See http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/getting-to-know-css/#specificity for some explanation on how CSS specificity is calculated.

Some options to fix it in your case:

1. Replace `.blue` with `#wrapper-landing p.blue`
2. Add `!important` to the color definition in `.blue`
3. Rewrite the `#wrapper-landing p` selector into `p`

I would prefer option 3 (as it keeps your selectors as small as possible), than option 2 (!important for a helper class like `.blue` isn't that bad) and as last option 1 (as this creates even more specificity).